# Using entity form display modes

Tags: 8, entities

I have created a custom form display mode `my_mode` for nodes and wish to display node form using this mode instead of default one at a custom page. How can I do it?

`$this->entityFormBuilder()->getForm()` accepts an operation as a parameter, but not form mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Form modes and form operations are a bit strange. You also need to define a form operation through `hook_entity_type_alter()` to be able to use a custom form mode.

Which makes the UI to create form modes pretty useless, but ssshh, don't tell anyone :)

For an example, see `views_ui_entity_type_build()`: `$entity_type->setFormClass($operation, $class_name)`

Comment: Where did you read it? Is there any documentation with details how it should be done?

Comment: I didn't read it, I know it as I participated in the relevant issues. Updated the answer with references to an example.

Comment: http://lobsterr.me/post/how-render-programatically-custom-entity-form-mode-drupal provides a comprehensive explanation how it can be done.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed it is quite strange I find to have both operation and form display, but you do not especially need to have a form operation to use your display. You have to use `hook_entity_type_alter` though...

Here is the way for example to load the "super" form mode (if exists and is activated) :

```
/**
 * Implements hook_entity_form_display_alter().
 */
function my_module_entity_form_display_alter(&$form_display, $context) {

  // Load the right entity form display.
  $id = $context['entity_type'] . '.' . $context['bundle'] . '.super';
  $storage = \Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('entity_form_display');
  $change_display = $storage->load($id);

  // If form mode is activated, replace the given one with ours.
  if ($change_display) {
    $form_display = $change_display;
  }
}
```